# Unity not registering

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using unity in my MVC app

I have the following RegisterTypes method within my Bootstapper.cs file:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());

        container.RegisterType<IModelContext, ModelContext>();
        container.RegisterType<IModelRepository, ModelRepository>();
    }
```

I have the following controller:

```
public class APIScoresController : ApiController
    {
        private IModelRepository _repo;
        public APIScoresController(IModelRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Result> Get()
        {
            return _repo.GetResults();
        }
    }
```

I have the following Model Repo:

```
public class ModelRepository : IModelRepository
    {
        ModelContext _ctx;

        public ModelRepository(ModelContext ctx)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;
        }

        public IQueryable<DomainClasses.Result> GetResults()
        {
            return _ctx.Results;
        }
    }
```

When I try to execute the GET on the APIScoresController I get the following exception:

```
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'APIScoresController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor
```

I would have expected unity to create the required ModelContext and ModelRepository objects. Any ideas why it's not doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem caused by web api registration needing a different version of system.web.http. I was trying to add web api to an existing mvc5 app - bad idea! I entered a form of dll hell that I hadn't experienced since days of VB6 COM. In the end my solution was to create a new solution with a web api project then retro fit the mvc project.